# Bad: Getting Mongo Network Error in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am getting mongo network error for the code, I have also whitelisted my IP address but still getting the error

I've already added my current IP address along with the 0.0.0.0 on the IP whitelist.

Below is a picture of the error message and the code I've written to connect it. I'm new to node.js and mongodb. I looked through all the solutions on here but none of them were able to solve this.
db.js

```
    require('dotenv').config();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

function connectDB(){
    mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_CONNECTION_URL , {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
    });
    const connection = mongoose.connection;

    connection.once('open', () =>{
        console.log('Database Connected');
    })
    .on('error', function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
}

module.exports = connectDB;
```

I have also tried setting up a new cluster and that also didn't worked

error

```
            at connectionFailureError 
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
            at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
            at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
        },
        topologyVersion: null,
        setName: null,
        setVersion: null,
        electionId: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
        primary: null,
        me: null,
        '$clusterTime': null
      },
      '' => ServerDescription {
        address: '',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 50302639,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host: . is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:*.mongodb.net, DNS:mongodb.net
            at connectionFailureError 
      }
    },
    stale: false,    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: 'atlas-',
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    common reversion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}
```

Comment: to be clear, no matter what you've tried, you always get `error: MongoNetworkError: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host: . is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:*.mongodb.net, DNS:mongodb.net` ??

Comment: What is `MONGO_CONNECTION_URL` set to when you run node?